# Node Restful with mongoose 4

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I am attempting to install node-restful with mongoose 4.  However, my command line response is

```
"peerinvalid The package mongoose does not satisfy its  

siblings'peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer node-restful@0.1.18 wants mongoose@~3"
```

Is there a way around this?  I am hoping to working with the more recent mongoose version.  Thanks!

Comment: node-restful now uses mongoose 4 so you shouldn't run into this problem anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faced the same problem today

I removed everything that I installed on npm before

```
 rm -rf ./node_modules ~/.npm
```

Then I installed the `node-restful` module first, it will install the correct version of `mongoose` as dependency

```
npm install --save node-restful
```

(I ran this over my project's working directory)

Answer (score 3):

The method mentioned by @RicardoQs does indeed get rid of the error but I just wanted to add something. If you install **node-restful** before **mongoose**, you will get the latest mongoose 3 release which is 3.9.7 . That version is unstable and it introduced [an annoying bug](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2757).

One thing you can do is:

```
npm uninstall mongoose
```

Then go inside package.json and add/modify the more stable mongoose dependency:

```
"mongoose": "3.8.23"
```

Finally, run

```
npm install
```

And now you have a more stable version of the mongoose package.
I recently ran into some issues with 3.9.7 and that's why I wanted to point this out.